# sequelize between date range always returning date today instead of date in records

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, select, sequelize.js

when i try to select where start_date :"2018-03-06T05:16:21.078Z and end_date : "2017-03-08T05:16:21.078Z but in the log always said

```
Executing (default):

SELECT `order_number`, `distribute_channel`, `sku_name`, `buyer_name`, `buyer_email`,
    `buyer_mobile`, `quantity`, `id_principal`, `total_nominal`,
    `posting_date`, `distribute_date`
FROM `central_ile` AS `centralIle`
WHERE `centralIle`.`order_number` = '213149361835030' AND
      `centralIle`.`created_date` = '2018-09-13 17:00:00'
LIMIT 0, 10;de here
```

here my script

```
let start_date= req.body.start_date
let end_date = req.body.end_date
let whereStatement = {}

 if (start_date && end_date) {
            whereStatement.created_date = {
                created_date : {
                    $between :[start_date , end_date]
                },
            }
        }
      let centralIleData = await CentralIle.findAll({
            raw:true,
            nest:true,
            where : whereStatement,
       })
```

whats actually wrong in my code ?

Comment: Of note, the actual raw query executed is using a `created_date` value which matches neither of your supposed inputs.  Are you certain that the code you showed us is actually what generated that query?

Comment: so how can i select it by date range?

Comment: I don't know Sequelize.  I only know that your `BETWEEN` logic is not making it into the actual query.

Comment: i tried ` $lt:start_date,
                        $gt:end_date` aswell, but doesnt works

Comment: Note also that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try it like this. it should work

```
whereStatement.created_date = { $between :[start_date , end_date] }
```